# hydro serial package stopbits enum is showing duplicate values

Tags: c++, serial, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am writing node to publish several sonar readings in a skirt being driven by an arduino.  My node listens on the serial port and advertises an array of sensor_msgs/Range.  I am depending on the ros-hydro-serial package to drive the serial port.  I wanted to handle communications between the arduino and the node with parameter values.  Therefore I am trying to look for and set all possibilities using ROS parameters.  (*Note: issuetracker does not seem to have anything on the serial package so I thought I would post here first.  I have taken out support for stopbits_one_point_five and am not being held up.  No urgency but would like to know if I am doing something wrong*)

---

I was using the attributes of a serial connection in a switch and received a compiler error.  "error: duplicate case value".

```
<snip of code>
switch (foo) {
   . . . 
   case serial::stopbits_one_point_five :
      this;
      that;
      break;
   case serial::stopbits_two :   //compiler issues the duplicate case value error for this line
      the other;
      break;
    . . . 
}
</snip>
```

I note in looking at the header it contains.

```
<snip of the ROS hydro serial.h header>
/*!
 * Enumeration defines the possible stopbit types for the serial port.
 */
typedef enum {
  stopbits_one = 1,
  stopbits_one_point_five,
  stopbits_two = 2
} stopbits_t;
</snip>
```

This has the affect of assigning the same value for the stopbits_one_point_five and the stopbits_two values.

My environment:
Ubuntu 12.04
gcc 4.6.3

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131561/hydro-serial-package-stopbits-enum-is-showing-duplicate-values/) by [kurt.christofferson](https://answers.ros.org/users/4082/kurt.christofferson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-02-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This bug was fixed in this pull request:

https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/pull/41

It should be fixed in `serial` >= `1.1.6`. The version in hydro is still `1.1.5`, I'll correct that now.

**EDIT:** I have release `1.1.7` into groovy, hydro, and indigo. You can monitor the version available from the different debians for hydro here:

http://www.ros.org/debbuild/hydro.html?q=serial

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1